# Passando dados de um formulario em uma pagina para textbox de formularios de outra pagina

Tags: php

Como eu faço para passar os dados de um formulario(consulta.php) de uma pagina para os textbox e um radioButton do formulario(cadastro.php) de outra pagina sem o action ? Porque eu tenho dois botoes submit para esse mesmo formulario(consulta.php) e não gostaria de usar o action para os 2, gostaria apenas de abrir a outra pagina(cadastro.php) com os textbox e radiobutton preenchidos pelo formulario da outra pagina(consulta.php) com um botao submit, o outro botão da pagina consulta.php eu gostaria que quando acionado permanecesse na mesma página(consulta.php).

O código do consulta.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['excluir'])){
            foreach($_POST['selecionado'] as $cpf){
               $sql = "DELETE FROM tbl_usuario WHERE cpf = '$cpf'";
                $result = mysqli_query($strcon,$sql) or die("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Erro ao tentar deletar usuário');</script>");
            }
        }
        else if(isset($_POST['alterarConsulta'])){
            foreach ($_POST['selecionado'] as $cpf){
                $linhas[] = 1;
            }
            if(count($linhas) == 1){
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_usuario WHERE cpf = '$cpf'";
                $result = mysqli_query($strcon,$sql) or die("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Erro no acesso aos dados');</script>");
                $dados = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                $altcpf = $dados['cpf'];
                $altnome = $dados['nome'];
                $altsexo = $dados['sexo'];
                $altidade = $dados['idade'];
                $altcidade = $dados['cidade'];
                $alttelefone = $dados['telefone'];
                $altemail = $dados['email'];

                header("Location: cadastro.php");
            }
            else{
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Selecione uma linha');</script>";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumindo que o botão esteja vinculado a linha que será editada e com um ID que faz relação ao mesmo pode-se usar

```
jQuery('.meuBotao').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    location.href = "meudominio.com?id="+id+"";
});
```

Essa forma irá redirecionar o usuário para outra página com um GET levando o ID do botão que foi clicado, esse ID deve ser o mesmo do usuário que desejas editar, e então na sua outra página você recupera esse ID com o método $_GET["id"] e faça uma pesquisa no banco de dados pelo mesmo com o ID, os dados retornados você adiciona ao formulário dentro de cada input value